# Why don't my rep points show?

Tags: bug

I realize one must participate on Stack Exchange for a certain length of time before becoming a "trusted member" and having upvotes show immediately on answers. I passed the "trusted membership" mark months ago. Since then, I get notifications of upvotes and they show in the space beside the answer, i.e. the 0 turns into a 1 or 2, depending on the score I am given. Recently, however, on one of my answers the 0 does not change even though I got notifications of points earned.

According to notifications my answer for "[Is it correct to say “the Lego got broken apart”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/252306/is-it-correct-to-say-the-lego-got-broken-apart/252309#252309)" earned +23 in the last 7 days. It does not show; i.e. the visible score still stands at 0.

What am I missing? Why don't my rep points show?

Comment: That is the net vote. You have a downvote on that answer that cancels out the upvote. So you have (+10 - 2 +15 = +23). Those are your rep points earned from that answer. But your score is 0 because of one down and one up on it.

Comment: Thanks, but why was I not informed of the downvote? In the past, I remember seeing downvotes. I forget if I just happened to check in or if there was a notification. Do you know the answer to this?

Comment: So, when you have just a downvote, your notification will not show the -2 rep loss. But then when you get an upvote on any one of your posts, your notification will show a net rep gain of +8. The green rep notification only shows the net gains.

Comment: Thanks so much! O the mysteries of math! But at least it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the number next to a post is its *net* score, calculated from all upvotes and all downvotes.

Even though you aren't notified of *only* a downvote, there are several things you can do to check:

- Click on the "trophy" icon to see your recent reputation changes, including downvotes.
  If the only voting that occurred on a topic was a downvote, you will see a **-2**. If other voting occurred to the topic, the number will be different. For example, if you get an upvote (which would normally display as **+10** and a downvote (which would normally display as **-2**), what you will actually see is **+8**.
- Select **Reputation** from your profile page to see a more detailed summary of reputation changes.
  This does more than just give a single number, and will do a better job of breaking down all of the individual voting that occurred.
- Since you are at 1,000 reputation, you can also click the **0** (or whatever the number is between the up arrow and down arrow) next to a post. It will expand and show you the specific upvotes and downvotes for that post that make up the net-score calculation.

Comment: Thanks for this information. However, the trophy icon does not show downvotes. I think it used to earlier this year but it no longer does. I had a downvote since last night and it does not show on the trophy icon but it shows when I click on the number between the arrows. On my network profile, all I can see if how many reputation points I have, not the downvotes.

Comment: @SarahBowman Yes, it does. You will see an entry of **-2**. That corresponds to a downvote. It will only be apparent if the *only* thing that happened to that topic was a downvote. If it's mixed with upvotes, the number will be different. (Or if there are several downvotes, it will be a multiple of **-2**.

Comment: I must have a bug because that is not how it shows. For https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/253543/is-gonna-finish-vs-is-finishing/253548#253548, in the trophy icon I am told I have +8. When I go to the answer and click on the 0, it says I have a +1 and a -1. The -1 is not noted separately in the trophy. I don't know how to send screenshots on here to prove it. But now I found the details on my profile. This morning I just found a line graph. I guess I'm still learning how to navigate the site, so this is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @SarahBowman That's how it's supposed to work. The fact that it shows you **+8** means that you got an upvote and a downvote. The **+10** (from the upvote) and the **-2** (from the downvote) combine to show you **+8**. That's normal.

Comment: Thank you so much!